# Django highcharts dynamic data

Tags: python, django, highcharts

Im setting up a data visualization using Highcharts and Django for a school.

I have a school which has 8 grades (std1, std2. std3,std4 etc etc....)
and in a year there are 6 exams( tem1, tem2, term3.. etc etc)

I want to calculate the data in the following format.

data= queryset.filter(grade1 and term1) in format of average percentage.

data1= queryset.filter(grade1 and term2) in format of average percentage.
etc etc till (grade1 and term6).

data2= queryset.filter(grade2 and term1) in format of average percentage.

6 exams and 8 grades = 48 different scores.

I have tried basic python coding using filtering and loops and list manipulation.

def get(self, request):

```
    queryset_list = Child.active.all()
    std1=[]
    total1=[]
    a = Child_reports.objects.filter(child__standard__exact='VII',  term__exact='1')

    for x in a:  

        std1.append(x.english)  
        std1.append(x.tamil)
        std1.append(x.hindi)
        std1.append(x.maths)
        std1.append(x.science)
        std1.append(x.social_science)

    for integer in std1:
        if integer !=0:
            total1.append(integer)   
    divide= len(total1)*100
    std1_term1= sum(total1)*100/divide

    context={

       'std1_term1': std1_term1
      }


    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

I got a total score of only one grade and one exam by writing so much code, if I follow the same procedure I will have to write it 48 times . That's DRY

Can you help me to simplify this code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zie69.png)

Comment: Hi @san, You have used highcharts tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Comment: I dont have a problem with highcharts nor with Django.. I just need some help in writing the logic to get the average scores.